# angular project from github ->The build command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found

Tags: javascript, angular, repository

i downloaded an angular project from github (by using  "git clone...")
when trying to build it (ng build) it gives me this error:

The build command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

old repositories?

Comment: may be you are not inside project folder & run npm install before build command

Comment: i did npm install and i am in the directory in which also package.json is

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.